# Keras LSTM - Categorical Cross Entropy falls to 0

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently trying to compare some RNNs and I have an issue only with the LSTM and I have no idea why.

I'm training with the same code/dataset a LSTM, SimpleRNN and GRU. For all of them the loss decrease normally. But for the LSTM, after a certain point (loss around 0.4), the loss directly falls to 10e-8. If I try to predict an output, I only have Nan.

This is the code :

```
nb_unit = 7
inp_shape = (maxlen, 7)
loss_ = "categorical_crossentropy"
metrics_ = "categorical_crossentropy"
optimizer_ = "Nadam"
nb_epoch = 250
batch_size = 64

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM( units=nb_unit, 
                input_shape=inp_shape, 
                return_sequences=True, 
                activation='softmax'))  # I just change the cell name
model.compile(loss=loss_,
              optimizer=optimizer_,
              metrics=[metrics_])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("lstm_simple.h5",
                            monitor=loss_,
                            verbose=1,
                            save_best_only=True,
                            save_weights_only=False,
                            mode='auto',
                            period=1)
early = EarlyStopping( monitor='loss',
                       min_delta=0,
                       patience=10,
                       verbose=1,
                       mode='auto')

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
                    epochs=nb_epoch, 
                    batch_size=batch_size, 
                    verbose=2, 
                    callbacks = [checkpoint, early])
```

This the the output of GRU and LSTM with the same input :

```
Input :
[[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
  [0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
  [0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
  [0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
  [0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
  [0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]]


LSTM predicts :
[[[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]]]


GRU predicts :
[[[ 0.     0.54   0.     0.     0.407  0.     0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.005  0.66   0.314  0.     0.     0.001]
  [ 0.     0.001  0.032  0.957  0.     0.004  0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.628  0.     0.     0.     0.372  0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.555  0.     0.     0.     0.372  0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.996  0.319  0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.     0.167  0.55   0.     0.     0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.486  0.     0.002  0.     0.51   0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.001  0.     0.     0.992  0.499  0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.     0.301  0.55   0.     0.     0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.396  0.001  0.007  0.     0.592  0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.689  0.     0.     0.     0.592  0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.001  0.     0.     0.997  0.592  0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.     0.37   0.55   0.     0.     0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.327  0.003  0.025  0.     0.599  0.   ]
  [ 0.     0.001  0.     0.     0.967  0.599  0.002]
  [ 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.002  0.874]
  [ 0.004  0.076  0.128  0.337  0.02   0.069  0.378]
  [ 0.006  0.379  0.047  0.113  0.029  0.284  0.193]
  [ 0.006  0.469  0.001  0.037  0.13   0.295  0.193]]]
```

For the loss, you can find below the last lines of the fit() history:

```
Epoch 116/250
Epoch 00116: categorical_crossentropy did not improve
 - 2s - loss: 0.3774 - categorical_crossentropy: 0.3774 - val_loss: 0.3945 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 0.3945

Epoch 117/250
Epoch 00117: categorical_crossentropy improved from 0.37673 to 0.08198, saving model to lstm_simple.h5
 - 2s - loss: 0.0820 - categorical_crossentropy: 0.0820 - val_loss: 7.8743e-08 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 7.8743e-08

Epoch 118/250
Epoch 00118: categorical_crossentropy improved from 0.08198 to 0.00000, saving model to lstm_simple.h5
 - 2s - loss: 7.5460e-08 - categorical_crossentropy: 7.5460e-08 - val_loss: 7.8743e-08 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 7.8743e-08
```

Or the evolution of the loss based on Epochs.

[image]

I previously tried it without Softmax and with MSE as loss function and I didn't get any error.

If needed, you can find the notebook and script to generate the dataset on Github (https://github.com/Coni63/SO/blob/master/Reber.ipynb).

Many thanks for your support,
Regards,
Nicolas

#### EDIT 1:

The root cause seems to be the Softmax function which vanished. If I stop it before it crashed and display the sum of the softmax for every timestep I have :

```
LSTM :
[[ 0.112]
 [ 0.008]
 [ 0.379]
 [ 0.04 ]
 [ 0.001]
 [ 0.104]
 [ 0.021]
 [ 0.   ]
 [ 0.104]
 [ 0.343]
 [ 0.012]
 [ 0.   ]
 [ 0.23 ]
 [ 0.13 ]
 [ 0.147]
 [ 0.145]
 [ 0.152]
 [ 0.157]
 [ 0.163]
 [ 0.169]]


GRU :
[[ 0.974]
 [ 0.807]
 [ 0.719]
 [ 1.184]
 [ 0.944]
 [ 0.999]
 [ 1.426]
 [ 0.957]
 [ 0.999]
 [ 1.212]
 [ 1.52 ]
 [ 0.954]
 [ 0.42 ]
 [ 0.83 ]
 [ 0.903]
 [ 0.944]
 [ 0.976]
 [ 1.005]
 [ 1.022]
 [ 1.029]]
```

With a Softmax of 0, the next step will try to divide by 0. Now I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just post my current solution in case someone else face this issue in the future.

To avoid vanishing, I've added a simple Fully-connected layer with the same output size as the input and it worked properly afterward. This layer allows another "configuration" of the output of LSTM/GRU/SRNN and avoid the output to vanish.

This is the final code :

```
nb_unit = 7
inp_shape = (maxlen, 7)
loss_ = "categorical_crossentropy"
metrics_ = "categorical_crossentropy"
optimizer_ = "Nadam"
nb_epoch = 250
batch_size = 64

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=nb_unit, 
               input_shape=inp_shape, 
               return_sequences=True))     # LSTG/GRU/SimpleRNN
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))  # New
model.compile(loss=loss_,
              optimizer=optimizer_,
              metrics=[metrics_])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("lstm_simple.h5",
    monitor=loss_,
    verbose=1,
    save_best_only=True,
    save_weights_only=False,
    mode='auto',
    period=1)
early = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='loss',
    min_delta=0,
    patience=10,
    verbose=1,
    mode='auto')
```

I hope this can help someone else :)

Comment: Why did you set `return_sequences` to `True`? I get errors when I set it to `False` such that I only use the last timestep.

Comment: I don't remember which project it was at this time unfortunately, I probably needed it the that time. what is the error ?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for getting back to me. The error is `Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 6 for 'generator/Squeeze'`. It's something to do with the fact that if I set `return_sequences=False` then the output dimension I get is `batch_size x num_features` where if `True` it would have been `batch_size x sequence_length x features`. So it seems like `categorical_crossentropy` or something doesn't like that. Anyways, you would probably need more context to be able to assist so no worries.

Comment: Yes, with a returned sequence you will add the "time" dimension, Your expected value should also contain it otherwise it will fail. If your expected result is simply the last result, you should not return the sequence.